# Expanded widget with minimum height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

Context of my problem: `Expanded` widget **shrink** its child widgets to **zero height** if required and **ignore** its children **constraints**.

Goal: **preventing** an expanded `widget` from shrinking to **less than its child size** so that its widgets won't get destroyed.

In addition, I need the widget to **take all available space** and expand its child.

Side note:
`Container` is used for allocating height space to make `expanded` react to the change in space

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: LimitedBox(
                maxHeight: 200,
                child: Text(
                  'Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text Test dummy text ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            height: 105,
            width: 200,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the unwanted current output:

[image: Expanded behavior that is required]

`Expanded` normal behavior:

[image: Shrinking behavior that is NOT required]

Comment: do you want second output?

Comment: No. I want to prevent first output

Answer (score 10):

Use `Flexible` widget and add the `Container` with min-height, The size of blue container will increase as the text increases.

```
 Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( 
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minHeight: 200, minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Text(
                    'Sample Text',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              height: 105,
              width: 200,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
  ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This solution will not solve my problem,
I need both expanding and prevent shrinking over text behavior

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want now, Can you describe more?

Comment: I want to add minimum height to expanded widget so that it will not shrink smaller than that size

Comment: No , its not what i want
i want you to try that:
First remove `SingleChildScrollView` then try to change the `Container` `height` from *100* to *2000*.
you will notice that the `Flexible` shrink to very small size and take over the text.
I want to prevent this behavior of shrinking over text...
i want to get error that`container` is overflow its size ... 
you will say just remove `Flexible` widget, but i want the widget to be Flexible in expanding because i use this expanding behavior in animation.
thanks

Comment: so in few words .. i need `Flexible` with `minHeight` property

Comment: This is extact which you want currently, as FLexible with min height, also you must have singlechildsrollView if your min hight is big